# cURL ProxyTunnel option in Java

Tags: java, php, curl, proxy

I would like to reproduce the cURL proxytunnel option, in Java. I'm using the Apache HttpClient library, but am open to change.

I have software for a client who is using a proxy; the only way we can get through that proxy is by using the proxytunnel option when testing with cURL. We'd love to get that behavior working with our current code. Their proxy is SQUID HTTP Proxy.

Thanks!